# Weird table tag at markdown email

Tags: laravel, email, markdown

Laravel 6.2

Here's the view:

```
@component('mail::message')

    @component('mail::panel')
    Some text
    @endcomponent

    @component('mail::button', ['url' => config('app.url')])
    Name: {{$attendee->name}}
    @endcomponent

@endcomponent
```

Between the panel and the button i get:

`<table class="action" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">`

Does anyone knows the reason for this?

Comment: can you provide the email html source?

Answer (score 3):

Answered.
It was the indentation, markdown parses indents as formatting.

```
@component('mail::message')

@component('mail::panel')
Some text
@endcomponent

@component('mail::button', ['url' => config('app.url')])
Name: {{$attendee->name}}
@endcomponent

@endcomponent
```